# ngIf - else into ngFor Angular Firestore Array Objects

Tags: angular, firebase, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I have a firestore collection called users where i have an array of objects studyList where i add the documents bought by the user.

[image]

What i'm trying to do is: when the user clicks on a document to check if that document is already in his studyList, if it is to show "OWNED" and if it is not to show a button to buy.

That's my HTML code for ngFor:

```
<div *ngFor="let document of user.studyList; index as i">
    <div *ngIf="document.id == documentId; else noOwn">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <button class="btn btn-large" [disabled]="true">Owned</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ng-template #noOwn>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <button class="btn btn-large" (click)="addToStudyList(user)">Buy</button>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

The button Buy is showed the number of times the condition is false(number of other documents in the studyList), like this:

[image]

What i want is to show only ONCE 'OWNED' or the Buy button. Can you help me? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place *ngFor in the second div and you should be fine

```
<div>
 <div *ngFor="let document of user.studyList; index as i">
   <div *ngIf="document.id == documentId; else noOwn">
     <div class="col-md-2">
       <button class="btn btn-large" [disabled]="true">Owned</button>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <ng-template #noOwn>
  <div class="col-md-2">
   <button class="btn btn-large" (click)="addToStudyList(user)">Buy</button>
  </div>
 </ng-template>
</div>
```

Comment: I get this error:   Error: Template parse errors:
Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one attribute prefixed with * ("      </div>

Comment: I've corrected the sample. Use *ngIf in another child div

Comment: Unfortunately it's still the same, only the alignment is different

Comment: You can take Owned button as well to get it out from ngFor.

Comment: I can't recreate everything but maybe this helps: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-teelve

Comment: The problem is that i'm using *ngIf="condition"; else noOwn. That's why it doesn't matter where it it the div, it will be shown anyway the number of times the condition is false. I don't know how to do this

Comment: Do you know a way to check if this documents exist in the studyList array and i won't have to use this ngFor anymore. I tried using array-contains in the collection but it did not work.

Comment: Can you tell me the structure of the array?

Comment: The array is the type DocumentInterface  {
    title?: string;
    language?: string;
    description?: string;
    cover?: string;
    price?: number;
    numberPages?: number;
    structure?: string;
    author?: string;
    category?: string;
    field?: string;
    id?: string;
    userUid?: string;
    urlDocument?: string;
    profit?: number;
} and this is in the user collection (like in the first photo). I want to check if this.document.id is equal with documentId

Comment: Did you tried using filter? For example 
const arrayWithOwnedBtn = originalArray.filter(p => p.id === documentId);
const arrayWithBuyBtn = originalArray.filter(p => p.id !== documentId);
And then use ngFor

Comment: But the array is in the users collection, how to access it? I tried something like this in my service to get the studyList  getStudy(document: DocumentInterface) {
    this.documents = this.afs.collection('documents', ref => ref.where('studyList','array-contains',document)).valueChanges();
    return this.documents;
  }

Comment: Thats why please share the list into the stackblitz, trust me I will be able to help you much faster like that

Comment: I managed to add this studyList into an array and to filter it:            this.study = user.studyList;
           const ownedDoc = this.study.filter(doc => doc.id == this.documentId);
           const notOwned = this.study.filter(doc => doc.id != this.documentId); and the ownedDoc is the element i need.

Comment: And this is my html, i can't check if it's something in that array and this will fix my problem: <div>
             <div *ngIf="ownedDoc?.length != 0; else noOwn">
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <button class="btn btn-large" [disabled]="true">Owned</button>
            </div>
             </div>
            
           
           <ng-template #noOwn>
            <div class="col-md-2">
             <button class="btn btn-large" (click)="addToStudyList(user)">Buy</button>
            </div>
           </ng-template>
          </div>

Comment: Does that fixed your problem bud ? Its hard to read the html comments :)

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I don't know that condition to put in my *ngIf to check if it's empty because ownedDoc.length != 0 it's not working

Comment: Its ok it happens, happy coding bud